# Top N Query - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would i return Top N Queries from SQL Server. I know how it is done in Oracle

`SELECT Empno, Ename, Job, Mgr, Hiredate, Sal
   FROM
   (SELECT Empno, Ename, Job, Mgr, Hiredate, Sal
      FROM Emp
      ORDER BY NVL(Sal, 0) DESC)
   WHERE ROWNUM < 6;`

But how is the same query written in SQL Server ?. I never worked on SQL Server. So any classic solution is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you googled "Top N Queries from SQL Server", any of the first 100 results would probably give you the answer.

Comment: Then i would have not joined SO

Comment: @all Thanks for your answers. I didnt know it was so simple in SQL Server.

Comment: I did lot of them turned up, so posted, basically i have no idea about SQL Server. Anyways i finally got the answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL server you achieve this behavior like so:

```
SELECT TOP 6 Empno, Ename, Job, Mgr, Hiredate, Sal FROM Emp ORDER BY NULLIF(Sal, 0) DESC;
```

Comment: That was mine. I retracted it as probably somewhat unnecessary. `NVL` is not valid SQL Server syntax. You need to replace with `NULLIF`.

Comment: Gotcha. I've never used an Oracle database and wasn't sure if that was some sort of user defined function. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy:

```
SELECT TOP 100 ....
```

Comment: But does TOP in SQL Server give you, most recent row data? Like how we can display most recent news items?

Comment: @user9009: Just add order by CreatedDate desc to get latest items

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
select top <n> ....
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `select top N`, like this:

```
SELECT TOP 6 Empno, Ename, Job, Mgr, Hiredate, Sal FROM (SELECT Empno, Ename, Job, Mgr, Hiredate, Sal FROM Emp ORDER BY NVL(Sal, 0) DESC);
```

Comment: Your answer contains an unnecessary subquery.

Comment: Well the main focus was on the TOP N syntax

Answer (score 1):

Just use `TOP` in the select to get the first values acording to the order clause, or if it doesn´t exisits, acording to the key or indexes.

```
SELECT  top <n> *
FROM    Table1
ORDER BY OrderCol <desc>
```